# Question closed as duplicate with dupe target closed for being opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

We have this question: [Using “std::cout” vs “using std::cout”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51042446/using-stdcout-vs-using-stdcout).
It was closed as a duplicate, quite reasonably - this question is asked over and over again, partly due to existance of [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice?noredirect=1&lq=1) - it's a natural follow-up question after reading this.
But then, duplicate points to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843068/c-best-practice-using-stdcout-vs-stdcout). It was closed for being primarily opinion-based. It has 1 upvote and 1 answer (accepted) with 2 upvotes.

Is it proper to mark a duplicate to a closed question? And are there really no better duplicates to that topic? One seemingly on point I could propose is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874756/should-using-stdcin-and-using-stdcout-be-avoided-or-encouraged). Again, there were concerns about question being POB, but it seems to me that it could be a good question (and possible dupe target for future ones) with a bit of cleaning up.